# How do I weigh images and then add them up efficiently in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector, vectorization, linear-algebra

I need a kind of volume-vector 'dot product' of sorts. Here is the problem:

I have a `2x3x4` volume, which is a nothing but a bunch of `4` `2x3` images one after the other. Let's call it volume `vol`.

I also have a `4x1` vector, and let us call it `vec`.

I want my output to be a weighted sum of each image. Thus my output will be a `2x3` image. It will be formed by taking:

```
output = vol(:,:,1).*vec(1) + vol(:,:,2).*vec(2) + vol(:,:,3).*vec(3) + vol(:,:,4).*vec(4)
```

I can put this in a for-loop, but I was wondering if there was an easier way of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfect case for **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** after re-arranging dimensions of `vec`with **[`permute`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)** to let `vec` expand onto the size of `vol` and let elementwise multiplication happen and finally use `sum` to fetch the desired result -

```
sum(bsxfun(@times,vol,permute(vec,[3 2 1])),3)
```

Or use matrix multiplication with some **[`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)**'s -

```
reshape(reshape(vol,[],numel(vec))*vec,size(vol,1),[])
```

Comment: Nice answer. I am not really getting the permute function though, even after the documentation. What I dont get specifically is what/how exactly the [3 2 1] is... doing..., and why it needs to be done that way. Thanks,

Comment: @Learnaholic Well that `permute(vec,[3 2 1])` was to create singleton dimensions at 1st and 2nd dimensions, so that when we use it with `bsxfun`, those singleton dimensions would be expanded so as to match with the size of `vol` and then elementwise multiplication would take place because we have also supplied the function handle `@times` into it. This `expansion` thing would be more clear if you could follow the basic idea behind the implementation of `bsxfun`. Please refer to its documentation as that would help a lot there.

Comment: Yeah, bsxfun I got. The permute was what I was having problems with. I think I get it now, thanks!

Comment: I also see from your profile that you are the vectorization king! :)

Comment: @Learnaholic Well let's just say that I think it's a shame if you are using a high level software platform like MATLAB and still using for-loops ;)